# When I put my shot into Premier, the top half of the shot is cut off. How can I scroll up so I can see the top of the shot?

Tags: video

My phone is I believe an Android A8. I filmed with the phone upright, in I guess portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the Effect Controls panel:
https://helpx.adobe.com/au/premiere-pro/using/viewing-adjusting-effects-keyframes.html

As the help says, there are several standard effects added to a clip in the timeline, the effect you want to look for is Motion. Select the clip in the timeline, go to the Effect Controls panel, and expand the Motion effect. Inside you'll see Position and Scale, Position has two numbers, horizontal then vertical - if you adjust the vertical, you can scroll it up to see the top of the image. You could also scale the image to fill the frame (zoom in), or scale it so that you can see the whole phone image instead (zoom out).

Just play around with the various options in the Motion panel to get a better idea of what you can do to manipulate your image, it's fairly intuitive.